# Unable to read file from within rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I have this rake task which reads a file.

```
desc "Dump with images."
task :dump_with_images => :environment do
  yaml_path = Rails.root + 'db/data.yml'

  # output: "" -- empty string
  puts File.open(yaml_path).read.inspect
  [...]
end
end
```

If I read and inspect the file from outside of the task,

```
yaml_path = Rails.root + 'db/data.yml'
puts File.open(yaml_path).read.inspect

desc "Dump with images."
task :dump_with_images => :environment do
```

It gives me some data:

```
zeromodulus@kosuna:~/projects/recipes$ rake dump_with_images
"\n---\nphotos:\n  columns:\n  - id\n  - created_at\n  - updated_at\n  - recipe_id\n  - image_file_name\
```

I don't understand why I can read the exact same file just outside of the task, but not in the task.

When I inspect yaml_path, they're both the same, and the file definitely has data in it.

Comment: This should work. See https://gist.github.com/tamouse/1f73c79b5e4675e498b7

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was opening a file stream and not closing it, and then later on in the code attempting to open that same file stream again.

I've wrapped the file reading code in a block,

```
File.read(file_path, "r") do |f|
  YAML.load_stream(f)
end
```

Which has solved the problem.

Update:

The problem has resurfaced, even though I have opened/closed file streams properly. The problem probably lies elsewhere, but I couldn't figure it out, so I decided to abandoned yaml_db and just use the standard db/seeds.rb